# Orbeon Forms - Multiple email addresses in a single email address control

Tags: email, orbeon

Can I please know if there is any standard way/syntax that support adding multiple email address in one email control. Suppose I need to add multiple email recipients in one email control is there a way to add those address? When I separate from comma an error is thrown. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in Email Address field only supports one email. If you need to capture multiple email addresses, you could:

1. Create a Repeated Grid grid in which you place the Email Address field.
2. Create your own component, using [XBL](https://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/xbl/), that supports multiple addresses.

If you're after a simple solution, #1 is the way to go. If you want to have as much control as possible over how the field behaves and can afford to invest the necessary time and energy into building an XBL component, then #2 might the best option for you.